# How to set default values to the properties of dynamically loaded types at runtime for XML serialization

Tags: c#, reflection, types, instantiation

I need to serialize dynamically loaded types' classes using XMLSerializer.

When using XML serializer non initialized values are not being serialized. I dont have control over the assemblies I am working with so can not use XML attributes for specifying default values on properties. So I think I need to set all properties and sub properties to their default values recursively and then serialize. ( Please let me know if there is any better way )

Followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2646224/c-recursive-reflection-generic-lists-setting-default-properties) :

Activator.CreateInstance(propType);

but above line complains about not having a parameterless constructor for some types.

Tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/390578/creating-instance-of-type-without-default-constructor-in-c-using-reflection) :
subObject = FormatterServices.GetUninitializedObject(propType); 
but this one gives an error "value was invalid" with no inner exception.

Please let me know if you need any further information.

Answer (score 1):

If the types in question don't have public parameterless constructors, you'll struggle. You can get around the attributes issue by using the [constructor overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/65k4wece(v=VS.100).aspx) that accepts  a [`XmlAttributeOverrides`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlattributeoverrides.aspx) object, which you can use to fully configure the serializer including the default value (via [`XmlAttributes.XmlDefaultValue`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlattributes.xmldefaultvalue.aspx)), but some things you can't do - and get around the constructor limitation is one of them.

What is the scenario here?

- if you want xml, then I would introduce a DTO layer: some objects that look *like* the ones you're talking about, but are simple and under your control. Ideal for `XmlSerializer`. You then write code to map between the two
- if you just want serialization (and xml is an implementation detail) then there are other serializers that may help. [`DataContractSerializer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.datacontractserializer.aspx) or [protobuf-net](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf-net/), for example; either would be more versatile here.